# How can I replace youtube / vimeo url with embed code in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, vimeo

I've tried replace youtube and vimeo url with embed code in javascript code.

I've used this code:

**EXAMPLE 1:**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divContent"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$("#divContent").html('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc <br /> http://vimeo.com/82495711 <br /> http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc');

$('#divContent').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="200" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" width="200" height="100" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');

});
```

**DEMO EXAMPLE 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/88Ms2/301/ - It's not working.

**EXAMPLE 2**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divContent">
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
    <br />
http://vimeo.com/82495711
    <br />
http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('#divContent').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="200" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" width="200" height="100" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');

});
```

**DEMO EXAMPLE 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/88Ms2/300/ - It's working

I've retrieved a data from database using ajax. I need the data with html code insert into div using javascript. How can I modify the example 1 to the correct code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In example 1, change the javascript code to:

```
$('#divContent').contents()
    .filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType === 3;
     })
    .map(function(index, text){
        $(text).replaceWith(
            text.textContent.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="200" height="100" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1" width="200" height="100" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>')
        );    
    })
```

It should work now.

Comment: You may look for anything but a space since there could be some more text after the url this can be made doing this: ([^\ ]+) instead of (.+) here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/w5grvL5q/